# How can I launch the tutorial for the GNU info pages?

Tags: info

I would like to learn how to use the `info` pages - i.e. the documentation for GNU programs.
If I run `info` from a terminal, the `info` program launches

```
File: dir,      Node: Top,      This is the top of the INFO tree.

This is the Info main menu (aka directory node).
A few useful Info commands:

  'q' quits;
  '?' lists all Info commands;
  'h' starts the Info tutorial;
  'mTexinfo RET' visits the Texinfo manual, etc.
```

however if I type <kbd>h</kbd> I get a man page for `info`, not the info tutorial. How can I launch the tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try starting from the command line with `info info`. Also, my info accepts `H` to enter the tutorial.

Comment: oh man this is embarassing, I tried it now and yes `H` works. I tried lower case `h` and `Ctrl-h` but not upper case!

Comment: yes, it is silly they dont mention `H` on the first page, but only `h`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the identical problem which I posted here:

[Cannot start the info tutorial in Debian 9 (stretch)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588026/cannot-start-the-info-tutorial-in-debian-9-stretch)

The solution (maybe overkill) was to install **emacs**, then the **emacs24-common-non-dfsg** package. I could then invoke the tutorial with `info info`, <kbd>h</kbd>. It also works with just `info`, <kbd>h</kbd>.