# Cannot start the info tutorial in Debian 9 (stretch)

Tags: linux, debian, info

I have the same problem as identified here:

[How can I launch the tutorial for the GNU info pages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292781/how-can-i-launch-the-tutorial-for-the-gnu-info-pages)

... but do not have sufficient reputation to make a comment. I don't think the single answer there is correct; all that <kbd>H</kbd> does is open the list of basic key bindings, as stipulated on the first page when `info info` is run.

I do vaguely remember the info tutorial; unsurprisingly it was very similar to the Emacs tutorial, and as @the_velour_fog mentions, hitting <kbd>h</kbd> only opens the man page, not the tutorial.

I tried the advice given in:

[Question about info program as described in "Introduction to Linux" by Machtelt Garrels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490374/question-about-info-program-as-described-in-introduction-to-linux-by-machtelt)

... and installed **texinfo-doc-nonfree** (and then the whole of **texinfo**) but this did not work.

I also tried installing **emacs** just in case. Inside **emacs**, typing <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> shows the **info** contents; <kbd>h</kbd> is specifically mentioned there ("... gives a primer for first-timers"), but hitting it throws the error on the status line *Info file info does not exist*.

A search in **aptitude** for `^info-doc` doesn't return too many results apart from the already installed **texinfo-doc-nonfree**), and none IMHO are likely candidates.

I have googled **cannot start "info tutorial"** and it appears there is a specific bug in Ubuntu [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texinfo/+bug/1804359), but I get the man page, rather than the error message in the bug report (*"Cannot find node '(info)Help'"*)

I would be interested in knowing if others have a similar result, if this may be a result of simply not identifying the correct doco package to install, or if I should report this to the maintainers. And should this question be merged with the original post from @the_velour_fog?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to install **emacs24-common-non-dfsg**, which was prompted by this post.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/info-file-emacs-does-not-exist

You may need a specific version of that package, e.g. **emacs[xx]-common-non-dfsg** to match the installed version of emacs.

It now works correctly when `info info` is invoked, then <kbd>h</kbd>. It also works with `info`, then <kbd>h</kbd>.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20:04: `emacs-common-non-dfsg`